# Returning specific property (text) from JSON object file in azure logic apps

Tags: json, azure, automation, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I'm not sure if I've horribly messed up the JSON file, or if I have encountered something that I am truly misunderstanding. Below is my JSON schema.

[image: JSON SCHEMA]

So when I parse it, it looks like the below.
[image: Parsed JSON]

Which to me looks pretty good. The problem is when I try to get a specific line out of the JSON to put in a automated email template, I get either nothing or the whole JSON output in one line. This is my work flow below, I have tried initializing variables using **variables('variable1')['0']** or **variables('variable1')['AP Outage Title']** , filter array, etc etc. Do I initialize a variable and place that specific property of the JSON file into that variable? I feel like I am so close but missing something critical.

I believe the JSON is an JSON object, but I could be wrong about that.

[image: Work Flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constructing the JSON Schema you can directly build a JSON Schema using `Use sample payload to generate schema` and then paste your JSON. Doing this will automatically generate a JSON Schema for you.

**STEP - 1:**

[image]

**STEP - 2:**

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Now you can generated with the objects inside the JSON

[image]

Below is the schema that got generated using the above steps.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "body": {
            "properties": {
                "AP Outage Title": {
                    "properties": {
                        "0": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "1": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "2": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "3": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "4": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "5": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "6": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "7": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "8": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "9": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "10": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "11": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "Revision Date": {
                    "properties": {
                        "0": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "1": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "2": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "3": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "4": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "5": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "6": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "7": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "8": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "9": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "11": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "18": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Alternatively, to get the values through expressions you can use `<Name_Of_The_Action_You_Are_Retrieving_The_Object>?['body']?['<Object_Name>']?['<String_Name>']`.

**Example:**

```
outputs('Compose')?['body']?['AP Outage Title']?['0']
```

Below is my logic app

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]